# routed events in multi-instanced user controls wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am building a WPF user control, which generates a SQL WHERE clause 'on the fly', so to speak.  That control, in turn, hosts an arbitrary number of another user control, which construct the individual conditions in that WHERE clause.
The instances of this child control contains several comboboxes, a text box (to enter the target value of the condition), and a couple of buttons -- one to add values to a list (e.g., for an 'IN' condition), and one to delete the statement -- and the control which represents it -- entirely.

Here's the issue: When I create an instance of that statement-building control, the control class registers a routed event, which is fired when the user clicks that 'Delete' button; this event is handled by the 'parent' user control, by removing the control from the stack panel that contains the list of 'WHERE' conditions.  And it works.  Once.  If I try to add another instance of that control, it throws an exception: "RoutedEvent Name 'DeleteRule' for OwnerType 'SQLBuilder.ClauseControl' already used."

I've spent the better part of a day Googling, and visiting every StackOverflow reference I found, but nothing deals specifically with the issue of registering routed events by multiple instances of a particular user control.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Here's the code where I'm registering the event:

```
    public partial class ClauseControl : UserControl
{
    // Register the routed event
    public readonly RoutedEvent DeleteRule = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("DeleteRule", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ClauseControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler DeleteRuleEvent
    {
        add { AddHandler(DeleteRule, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(DeleteRule, value); }
    }
```

... (Rest of class definition)

Comment: please include a relevant code (at least code where `the control class registers a routed event`)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!  the RoutedEvent has to be declared 'static'.  (At least, that's what worked for me; your mileage may vary.)